# How to include zeros at the end of an approximation

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy, approximation

I want to make a table for my calculus 1 class learning limits. I am calculating $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{sin(x)}{x}$. I am using the approximation given by N. The problem is with the expression up to 15 (or however many) digits. For example, calculating this with $x=.5$, I type

```
N[Sin[.5]/(.5),15]
```

The output is

```
.958851077208
```

which only has 12 decimal places. I assume this is because the last 3 (and the forever) are just zero. (Either that or Mathematica cannot calculate it to more than 12 digits, which I doubt). How can I get it to show it with all 15 digits and not just the 12 non-zero ones?

Comment: Look at `SetAccuracy` and `SetPrecision`.

Comment: Replace `.5` with `1/2`.

Comment: Thanks @ChipHurst! Why did this work?

Comment: The expression `Sin[.5]/.5` is evaluated first, hence you've computed a machine number first, which has a limited number of digits. If you use `1/2` instead, you'll have an *exact* value to take an arbitrary amount of digits from.

Comment: Thanks. If you make this an answer, I'll choose it.

Comment: Here are two links to Documentation Center articles that are relevant to your problem. [Controlling Precision](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ControlThePrecisionAndAccuracyOfNumericalResults.html) and [Numbers Overview](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumbersOverview.html)

Comment: This is also mentioned in the third example in the docs for [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
In[2580]:= ndigits = 20;
SetPrecision[Sin[0.5]/0.5, ndigits]

Out[2581]= 0.95885107720840601075
```

Comment: It's worth pointing that out this gives 20 digits of a roughly 16-digit-accurate result.  One might want a result that is accurate to 20 digits, in which case something else should be done.